# Angularjs: Databinding not working

Tags: angularjs, http, data-binding, binding

Binding a service/factory variable within a controller works perfectly unless the factory variable is initiated through $http. Can anyone explain why?

NOTE: Since controller.someVariable = factory.someVariable doesn't work. Currently I am referencing the factory variable directly for manipulation as 
factory.someVariable

**Controller:**

```
app.controller('SecondCtrl',function($scope,testFactory){
  $scope.obj = testFactory.obj;
  $scope.factory = testFactory;
  $scope.jsonData = testFactory.jsonData;   //Not Binding

  //Accessing $scope.factory.jsonData works while $scope.jsonData doesn't
});
```

**Factory:**

```
app.factory('testFactory', ['$rootScope','$http',function ($rootScope,$http) {

    var factory = {};

    factory.obj = { 'name':'Jhon Doe'};

    factory.jsonData;

    factory.fromjson = function() {
      $http.get("data.json")
        .success(function(data){
           factory.jsonData  = data.result;
        })

    }

    factory.fromjson();

    return factory;

}]);
```

**Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/wdmR5sGfED0jEyOtcsFz?p=preview

Comment: `$http` is async, you need to return the promise, you are trying to return immediately the data even if it hasn't come back from the server yet.  because these are both primitives, and not objects, they aren't "bound" to each other, you are trying to assign the value of one to the value of the other.

Comment: The factory.jsonData is only updated when the data is received from the server. At that time the controller variable that references the factory variable must update itself right?

Comment: the controller variable isn't going to update itself, no.  These are not objects, they are primitives.  In the first case, you are accessing the primitive property of the `factory` object, in the second case, you are accessing a primitive on `$scope`.

Comment: However, if you see in the plunker when I update `obj.name` from `FirstController` the same is updated in `SecondController`. These both controllers reference the same factory `obj`.

Comment: you still misunderstand.  your second option is not a **reference** assignment, it is a **value** assignment.  therefore, `$scope.jsonData` can only receive the **value** that is present on `testFactory.jsonData` ***at the time of assignment***.  If these were **objects**, then they would be a **reference** assignment instead.  This is not an angular issue, but a javascript assignment issue.

Comment: this is one of the most common pitfalls of angular, and is the commonly mentioned, but never clearly explained, "Always use a dot" argument.

Comment: So using factory obj would be the way to go forward? ie. using $scope.factory = testFactory and then referencing the variables within

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, the reason this is occurring is because `$scope.jsonData = testFactory.jsonData;` is a **value** assignment, and unfortunately that value isn't available from the server yet when this assignment occurs.  the other assignments work because they are **reference** assignments.

One quick but dirty way to solve this would be to declare `factory.jsonData = {};` instead of `factory.jsonData;`.  This would change the call to a reference assignment (object to object) and allow changes to one to propagate to the other.

Comment: I have a similar question but with a different objective, would like your opinion on it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33319779/typescript-declare-an-array-as-object-to-enable-angular-binding