# Typescript: Data bind between service and controller such that utilization of variable is simple

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Since value assignment doesn't bind data, this -> `this.arrayVal = someService.arrayVal` doesn't work. Is there a way to overcome this?

The goal here is to keep the assignment simple in HTML and controller ie. using `Ctrl.arrayVal` instead of `Ctrl.someService.arrayval`

**Controller:**

```
module Controllers {
    export class SomeController {

    arrayVal: Array<SomeModel>;

    static $inject = ['someService'];
    constructor(
    private someService: SomeService
    ){
         this.arrayVal = someService.arrayVal; 
//I would like to do this as it would keep the assignment simple in HTML -> Ctrl.arrayVal vs Ctrl.someService.arrayval
    }

}
}
```

**Service:**

```
class SomeService {
     arrayVal = $http.get('http://Address');
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to do will work in the controller. Your controller is getting a reference to the array in the service. However, if your service changes the array (like when the data is received) with a new assignment, you change the reference to a new array, which the controller is not using.

To make what you want happen, you need to avoid creating the new array in the service. Keep that reference the same, and push/splice items in/out of it.

Comment: @SunilD. It sounds good however, I would appreciate if there is another simple way of achieving this as the current suggestion seems like a hack.

Comment: this is the *exact opposite* of the issue you posted on asking for my assistance from.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184189/angularjs-databinding-not-working/33184454?noredirect=1#comment54440887_33184454.  In your case, this is a reference assignment, because `$http.get` returns a promise object, and the problem occurs here because when you completely replace one reference with another, angular doesn't update the bindings.  managing a local array and pushing/splicing data into and out of it is less of a hack than the alternative, which would involve using the `$compile` service.

Comment: @SunilD. @Claies Would angular.extend work for this purpose? replace `this.arrayVal = someService.arrayVal;` with `angular.extend(this.arrayVal, someService.arrayVal);`

Answer (score 1):

> Ctrl.arrayVal instead of Ctrl.someService.arrayval

You can just put `someService` directly on the scope. Then use `someService.arrayVal` in html *and* controller.

Comment: I am using `controller as` syntax so how would I be able to use `someService.arrayVal` directly?

Comment: @ShyamalParikh Typescript will automatically turn `public` or `private` constructor args into member variables of the class. Since your service is already private, this should just work b/c the service is a property of the controller. It's probably the least hackiest solution proposed so far, I do this myself from time to time and not sure why I didn't suggest it :)

Comment: @SunilD. I will try this out. Currently, I made it work with angular.extend so that the address reference is not modified.